# How can you assign the value Nothing to a control attribute declaratively in a VB.Net ASPX file?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If I have a control that has a read/write property of type **Nullable(Of Integer)** (or **Integer?**, if you prefer the shorthand), how can you assign the **Nothing** value as an attribute in the ASPX/ASCX definition (as opposed to setting it in the codebehind)?

E.g. a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` control has a read/write property called `MaxLength` of type `Integer`.  I can set this in the ASPX by including the property name as an attribute in the declaration, like this:

`<asp:TextBox id=”myTextBox” runat=”server” MaxLength=”30” />`

Indeed, I can set my `Integer?` property in the same way so long as I’m assigning an integer, but I want to set the property to `Nothing`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a data binding expression:

```
<my:MyControl runat="server" ID="mine" NullableProperty="<%# Nothing %>" />
```